# How to stop the Exchange 2010 server only -O365 migration

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, exchange-migration

I have recently done a migration to 365 and I have an in house Exchange 2010 server. As I expected there are people who are still connected to the old server even though there has been numerous emails regarding the update. I really wish I could shut down the Exchange server, so users with outdated setting will get bumped and we can ID them that way, but I have an inventory software running on that same server, so I can not physically turn it off.

What is the best way to stop the Exchange 2010 (ONLY) from running and responding without shutting it down.

Thanks

Comment: EEAA nails it.... got to the "services" and stop everything that starts with "Microsoft Exchange...." that will certainly get things stopped. Are these lingering users still receiving e-mail, though? Are they sending internally (with the recipients never getting the mail, because they are moved to Office 365)? Are you running Exchange in Hybrid mode with Office 365? Are you planning to retire Exchange services completely from your Active Directory Domain? Are you running DirSync or Azure AD Connect? Have you updated your "autodiscover" DNS record?

Answer (score 0):

Either stop all of the exchange-related services or modify the host firewall to block connections on mail-related ports.